# Notifications and quick settings panes stop working on iPhone

Tags: iphone, notifications

After some time the notification slidedown and quick controls slideup(?) suddenly stop working. IOS8, iPhone 6. After reboot they work again and then again don't (after maybe several days). When the phone is locked, both panes work correctly.

What could it be and how to fix it?

Comment: Update: Looks like it is gone for now. Still don't know what was it. Maybe some app blocked it and now it stopped?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a software fault, the best solution is to backup and reinstall our phone.

[This guide on Apple.com will explain how.](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT1414)